# How can I convert PyTorch Tensor to ndarray of Numpy?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, reshape, numpy-ndarray

The shape of my tensor is `torch.Size([3, 320, 480])`

Tensor is

```
tensor([[[0.2980, 0.4353, 0.6431,  ..., 0.2196, 0.2196, 0.2157],
         [0.4235, 0.4275, 0.5569,  ..., 0.2353, 0.2235, 0.2078],
         [0.5608, 0.5961, 0.5882,  ..., 0.2314, 0.2471, 0.2588],
         ...,

         ...,
         [0.0588, 0.0471, 0.0784,  ..., 0.0392, 0.0471, 0.0745],
         [0.0275, 0.1020, 0.1882,  ..., 0.0196, 0.0157, 0.0471],
         [0.1569, 0.2353, 0.2471,  ..., 0.0549, 0.0549, 0.0627]]])
```

I need something of shape 320, 480, 3 I guess

So, the tensor should look like this

```
array([[[0.29803923, 0.22352941, 0.10980392],
        [0.43529412, 0.34117648, 0.20784314],
        [0.6431373 , 0.5254902 , 0.3764706 ],
        ...,

        ...,
        [0.21960784, 0.13333334, 0.05490196],
        [0.23529412, 0.14509805, 0.05490196],
        [0.2627451 , 0.1764706 , 0.0627451 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Start with the method(s) that `pytorch` provides to create an array.  Once you have one, you can then perform the necessary `np.transpose` (see docs).

Comment: Hi, What is the difference between tensor.permute and np.transpose? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change device to host/cpu with .cpu() (if its on cuda), then detach from computational graph with .detach() and then convert to numpy with .numpy()

```
t = torch.tensor(...).reshape(320, 480, 3)
numpy_array = t.cpu().detach().numpy()
```

Comment: It is giving me something like this array([[[0.49019608, 0.4745098 , 0.42352942, ..., 0.23921569,
         0.24705882, 0.25882354],
        ..............

Comment: this just converts you tensor to an array. Ah do you want to reshape it too?

Comment: Yes, I need to make it (320, 480, 3)

Comment: hm ok. Thats weird because 320 * 480 * 3 = 3 * 320 * 480 = 460800 . Are you sure you are reshaping the right tensor?

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for me

```
t = torch.tensor(...).permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()
```